# Is there way to destruct elements in js more shorter and clean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, destructuring

I have this code:

```
const url = `https://the-cocktail-db.p.rapidapi.com/lookup.php?i=${action.id}`;

const { loading, data } = yield call(fetchData, url);
const { drinks } = data;
const [ details ] = drinks;
const { strDrink, strDrinkThumb, strInstructions, idDrink } = details;

const cocktail = { strDrink, strDrinkThumb, strInstructions, idDrink };

yield put(getCocktailDetails(cocktail, action.id, loading));
```

Is there way to make it more clean and short?

Can I do something like:

```
const [{val1, val2, val3}] = arrayOfObjects;
```

Comment: `const {loading, data: {drinks: [{strDrink, strDrinkThumb, strInstructions, idDrink}]}} = yield call(fetchData, url);`

Comment: Do you mean something like `const { drinks: [ strDrink, strDrinkThumb, strInstructions, idDrink ] } = data`?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can :

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{val1: 1, val2: 42, val3: 18}, {val4: 54}]
const [{val1, val2, val3}, {val4}] = arrayOfObjects;
console.log(val1, val2, val3, val4)
```